# Прокрутка до якоря без ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть кнопка, при клике на которую открывается вкладка. Хотелось бы добавить к ней прокрутку к верху вкладки, но `id` уже назначен, и все мои действия терпят крах.

Кнопка:

```
<a id="myButton" class="button" href="#download" data-toggle="tab"> название кнопки</a>
```

Код, который открывает вкладку:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#myButton").click(function() {
            $('#myTab2 a[href="#download"]').tab('show');
        });
    });
});
```

[Пример в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ohmi/9v3m8odq/2/)

Comment: вверх окна прокрутиться просто: [`scrollTo(0,0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) – методу передаются координаты (x,y) к которым надо прокрутить.

Comment: можно создать якорь через атрибут name: `<a name="..."></a>`

Comment: Толкать два `document.ready` разом - плохая затея.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $('#myTab2 a[href="#download"]').tab('show');
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9v3m8odq/3/